# Using google drive API to access my own "public" folder android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have a google drive account that i want people within a certain organization to be able to upload files to programmatically, and also as invisible as possible. as i'm following along the google drive SDK tutorials, i can't seem to find anything about uploading a file directly to MY drive account. all the tutorials seem to be talking about allowing users to upload a file to their own account. The other problem is that they seem to all require some user permission (which i don't want).

the idea is this -> there's about 100 ppl (very controlled on who gets access) that have a special build of an android/iOS build, and for these people, i want to periodically sample certain screenshots of how they use the app. i'm able to save the screenshot files to their device locally; however, i want a "semi-public" source of viewing on these files. so i've set up a google drive account so that i can accept these screenshots in to my account. however, i don't want the users to have to accept any permissions, or use their own account. Ideally, at the end, i can share my drive account folder (with these screenshots) with people that i select to share it with.

Is this even possible? If so, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Drive API for Android only supports authorizing the current user, however if you use the Google APIs Java client instead to access the Drive API you can store credentials for your account with the application and use those for all users of your app. Read more about authorization and the Java client [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2).

Comment: this is interesting. i'll have to give this a go some time. thanks!