# Android Google Drive API upload to my public folder

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm developing an app which will allow users to upload photos to my Google Drive public folder.
Currently, from online tips, i managed to do the upload process. However, each users can only upload the photo to their own Drive.
I've been searching the net for the tips, some are suggesting to use REST API but I don't know how to implement it. 
I've been reading [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#simple) guide and still don't know how to do it on android.
Can someone point show a simple way of uploading a file to public folder using REST API on android.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already managed to [upload a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads), the only problem is how to upload a file to public folder on Android. I have read in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275504) that Drive API for Android only supports authorizing the current user. You can file a [feature request](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/TESSj1GH1Xw) for this. This workaround might also help: *However if you use the Google APIs Java client instead to access the Drive API you can store credentials for your account with the application and use those for all users of your app. Read more about authorization and the Java client [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2).*